# what is signifcance of argument 'base' in strtol in c?

Tags: c, string, function

In string library function strtol ,there is a third argument called 'base'. man page says that this base should be between 2 to 36 or a special value 0.what is the significance of this argument while writing the code?I get the different output when I change the value of base in my code.but I do not understand the logic behind change of base and difference in outputs...simply-I am not able to predict my output with change of base.

Comment: Have you tried with large numbers? 20 in base 10 is something different than 20 in base 16.

Comment: Try `strtol("100",NULL,2)`

Comment: then you should stop using single digit as test case.

Comment: Did you read _all_ of the manpage?

Comment: @Evert yes,there is change in output now.

Comment: See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It refers base of number system, eg hexadecimal,octal,binary
eg if you run this small program

```
#include<stdio.h>
int  main()
{
char str[]="0x16";
char str1[]="0100";
char str2[]="0111";
printf("%d,%d,%d",strtol(str,NULL,16),strtol(str1,NULL,8),strtol(str2,NULL,2));
}
```

It gives output as: 22,64,7
hex 0x16 is converted to decimal 22
0100 ie 100 octal is converted to 64 decimal
binary 0111  is converted to 7 decimal

Comment: You've not mentioned `0` as the base — which is rather important.

Answer (score 3):

The `base` argument instructs the function to treat the input as having a specific numeric base.

For example, if your string contains a number represented as hexadecimal, you would use base 16.  If it is binary, you would use 2...  *etc*

Non-standard bases are supported up to base 36, where "digits" with a place value of 10 to 35 use the letters 'a' to 'z'.

The standard bases we tend to use as programmers are: 2, 8, 10, and 16.  If you use the special value of base 0, then the function will detect the numeric base in the same way as a C compiler interprets integer values in your code:

- binary (base 2) is prefixed with `0b`
- octal (base 8) is prefixed with `0`
- decimal (base 10) has no prefix, but must begin with a non-zero digit
- hexadecimal (base 16) is prefixed with `0x`.